# Cannot assign to immutable expression of type

Tags: swift

```
 func buttonAction(sender:radioButton!) {
    let tempGetTestDesc = dspResult[sender.indexPathSection!]["tests"] as! NSMutableDictionary
    let temp = tempGetTestDesc["tests"]as! NSMutableArray
    var tem = temp[sender.indexPathRow!] as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
 switch sender.tag{
    case 110:
        tem["sideValue"] = "Left"
    case 111:
         tem["sideValue"] = "Right"
    case 112:
          tem["sideValue"] = "Both"
    case 113:
        tem["contrastValue"] = "Y"
    default:
        break
    }
```

It cause no error from above code. However it doesn't update the value inside dspResult. it only updates the value inside tem. So i use the following code to update the value.

```
(((dspResult[sender.indexPathSection!]["tests"] as! NSMutableDictionary)["tests"]as! NSMutableArray)[sender.indexPathRow!] as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)["contrastValue"] = "Y"
```

However, it doesn't work. Cannot assign to immutable expression of type

Comment: `(((dspResult[sender.indexPathSection!]["tests"] as! NSMutableDictionary)["tests"]as! NSMutableArray)[sender.indexPathRow!] as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)["contrastValue"] = "Y"` Yikes thats a lot of force-unwrapping

Comment: how can i update the value inside dspResult then??

Answer (score 0):

The reason is you unwrap the tem variable as `Dictionary`, `Dictionary` in swift is a `value type`, that means, any variable assignment will cause the a new dictionary object is created and assign to the variable, instead of reference assignment.

```
 func buttonAction(sender:radioButton!) {
    let tempGetTestDesc = dspResult[sender.indexPathSection!]["tests"] as! NSMutableDictionary
    let temp = tempGetTestDesc["tests"]as! NSMutableArray
    var tem = temp[sender.indexPathRow!] as! NSMutableDictionary // <--- Instead of Dictionary
 switch sender.tag{
    case 110:
        tem["sideValue"] = "Left"
    case 111:
         tem["sideValue"] = "Right"
    case 112:
          tem["sideValue"] = "Both"
    case 113:
        tem["contrastValue"] = "Y"
    default:
        break
    }
```

You can copy and paste the following code to playground and you will know what I mean.

```
let a = NSMutableDictionary(dictionary: ["a": 1])
let aa = NSMutableArray(array: [a])
var b = aa[0] as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>  // <-- b is a new copy of a dictionary, so change the value in b, will not impact to the variable a
b["a"] = 2 
print(a["a"]!)

let c = aa[0] as! NSMutableDictionary // <--- c is reference to the origin dictionary a, so changing the value in c will change the value in a
c["a"] = 2
print(a["a"]!)
```